# Pandas Groupby with idxmax and transform to get the value of the largest index of each group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, transform

I have the following dataframe

```
       High    FlgVela  
0      177.73      1
1      178.48      2      
2      182.10      2      
3      182.48      3      
4      173.66      4
5      174.40      5
6      172.34      6
7      172.87      6
8      176.36      6
```

What is the correct way to get the maximum index value based on the FlgVela variable, just like the dataframe below.

```
       High    FlgVela  High_ValueIndexMax
0      177.73      1        177.73
1      178.48      2        182.10
2      182.10      2        182.10
3      182.48      3        182.48
4      173.66      4        173.66
5      174.40      5        174.40
6      172.34      6        176.36
7      172.87      6        176.36
8      176.36      6        176.36
```

I have tried the following logic but it returns the index and the expected result is the value of the index row.

```
df['High_ValueIndexMax'] = df.groupby(['FlgVela'])['High'].transform('idxmax')
```

Comment: Make it 'max' instead of 'idxmax'.

Comment: I don't understand *"but it returns the index and the expected result is the (whole?) value of the index row."* So within each group, you want a) the whole row pertaining to `.idxmax()`? b) simply the max value? (in which case just use `.max()` c) or else what?

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
df['High_ValueIndexMax'] = df.groupby(['FlgVela'])['High'].transform('max')
```

OUTPUT:

```
     High  FlgVela  High_ValueIndexMax
0  177.73        1              177.73
1  178.48        2              182.10
2  182.10        2              182.10
3  182.48        3              182.48
4  173.66        4              173.66
5  174.40        5              174.40
6  172.34        6              176.36
7  172.87        6              176.36
8  176.36        6              176.36
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire row pertaining to `idxmax()` within each group:

```
>>> df.loc[ df.groupby('FlgVela').idxmax()['High'] ]

     High  FlgVela
0  177.73        1
2  182.10        2
3  182.48        3
4  173.66        4
5  174.40        5
8  176.36        6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
idx=df.groupby(['FlgVela'])['High'].transform('idxmax').values
```

Finally:

```
df['High_ValueIndexMax']=df.loc[idx,'High'].values
```

Output of `df`:

```
        High    FlgVela     High_ValueIndexMax
0       177.73      1       177.73
1       178.48      2       182.10
2       182.10      2       182.10
3       182.48      3       182.48
4       173.66      4       173.66
5       174.40      5       174.40
6       172.34      6       176.36
7       172.87      6       176.36
8       176.36      6       176.36
```